# what method is called when Actionbar back/home button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, up-navigation

I have two activities first activity opens on app start and it holds fragment second activity is opened from that fragment, when I press home button second activity closes and in fragment methods  onDetach -> onAttach -> onResume is called, but if I close second activity with finish() or onBackPressed() fragment is never detached just onResume() is called.So my question is what method is called when home button is pressed and is there possibility to use same method to close activity for example on button press? Basically what I need is that fragment would call onDetach -> onAttach when I closing second activity.

Comment: The operating system takes care of calling the lifecycle methods. There's nothing you can do to affect it. Migrate your code from `onDetach` to a more appropriate method like `onPause` then, or have it in both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the fragment in e.g. `onDestroy()` of the activity, so the fragment will go through it's lifecycle methods

Answer (score 0):

The activities `onPause()` is called when pressing the home or back button. I just tried out using `finish()` and `onBackPressed()` which results in `onPause()` being called, too.

However, I am not sure whether there are differences when using fragments.

Android training concerning pausing and resuming: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Comment: Yes you are right but what I need is that fragment would call onDetach and onAttach when I'm closing second activity on button press